# How to put content in center of the screen

Tags: css, html

I am trying to put my things in the  tag at the center of the screen, but it is not working.

How can I put it in center of screen using HTML and CSS?
Where I am -

Code-

Result - [image: 1]

Comment: show us what you have tried so we don't suggest things you've already done.. also look into `margin` - can use it like `margin: 0 auto` to center things

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs i just updated it should i put margin?

Comment: great - your img 404s btw haha and see my answer and see if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a .child element you want to center inside a .parent element, You have 2 options:

1) Flexbox - You can use the following css:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: 
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  text-align: center; /*optional*/
}
```

2) Absolute positioning:

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center; /*optional*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you provided some code you have written, but if you want to center a tag you can do this:

**CSS**:

```
#parentTag{
   position: relative;
}

#myTagIWantToBeCentered{
    position: absoulte;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parentTag">
    <div id="myTagIWantToBeCentered">
       <!--stuff here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center content horizontally and vertically use this:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box_text {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red; 
    margin:3px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
 

<div class="box"><span class="box_text">0</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Bootstrap, you can easily add a class `text-center`. Normally, an (inline)-block element can be centered with css

```
.center { margin: 0 auto; }
```

It would be best if you could provide your code so we can suggest base on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSS Flexbox.  If you add

```
.class {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;     //Aligns the content vertically
    justify-content: center; //Aligns the content horizontally
}
```

to the parent html element.

For an example, have a look at this js-fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/adamturner93/brjotz2y/1/.

Answer (score -3):

You can try using HTML  Tag if you are not using HTML5.

Ex-

```
<center>This text will be center-aligned.</center>
```

If you are using HTML5 then you need to use css to modify.

```
<element>.<class> {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 6em
}
```

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and it is recommended to use a CSS align.
Also, `<center>` will put content horizontally in the middle of the parent div. 
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: also margin can be optimised to be `margin: 0 auto;`